# How to Integrate Jmeter Test Results with TestRail

Tags: jmeter, testrail

How to Integrate Jmeter Test Results with TestRail, please anyone help me on this with small example.

Comment: You need to leverage TestRail API in your JMeter test plan. http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/start

Comment: I am new to this, Can you please share small example for the same.

Comment: Do you have an API key with test rail? First you need to connect JMeter to Test Rail. Refer this link. http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/accessing and then you can use the `Results` API http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/reference-results

Comment: Thank You for help

Comment: May I post this in the answer? Will you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use TestRail API, that's true. It's a simple, ReST one.

To me it looks you got two options here.

1) Implement the custom Beanshell/JSR223 listener that would peek up the [Sample Result](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) data and push them into TestRail as the test is going.

Although I won't recommend that: it would apparently slows JMeter down, consume resources & may influence the test result recordings through that.

So you better opt for

2) Keep your Test Plan lean in JMeter, record results (like, `jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l test.jtl`) - and implement the auxiliary util to ingest them, parse & push into TestRail.

That way seems to be more effective & reliable, for obvious reasons.

PS Basically, there exists the third way, especially if you need the results coming live: stream the results using [Backend Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener). 
Although TestRail seems not having the stream API out of the box, so you're going to write a kind of a proxy that would transform Graphite stream (for example) into sequence of TestRail calls.
That's gonna be interesting, but apparently the trickiest of all solutions.